# Is the book wrong? Different inequality shown.

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

The problem is this:

---

[image]

---

And the proposed solution is this

---

[image]

---

To me, it's not obvious what so ever that the inequality shown in the solution is the same as the inequality asked for in the problem.

Can anyone shed some light at this?

Comment: Do you agree that we can move the terms to the other side?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Moving the $\nabla u$ and $u$ terms left we get.

$$ \frac{3}{4} ||\nabla u||^2 + \frac{1}{2} ||u||^2 \leq ||f||^2 + C||g||_\Gamma^2.$$  But it's still not on the form as in the question.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: It is then very simple to estimate things so that they are in the required form.

Comment: @JohnB You're right. I was so focused on only manipulating that inequality and never thought of re-estimating things till I get to the desired inequality. Thanks.